# How to use mlmodern fonts with Plain TeX or OpTeX?

Tags: fonts, plain-tex, optex

I would like to systematically use mlmodern fonts with Plain TeX and even OpTeX, but I am unable to convert the code of mlmodern.sty into a code which could be understood by the tex  or optex compilers. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For plain TeX you have to essentially repeat all the “fonts” part in `plain.tex`.

```
\font\tenrm=rm-mlmr10 % roman text
\font\preloaded=rm-mlmr9
\font\preloaded=rm-mlmr8
\font\sevenrm=rm-mlmr7
\font\preloaded=rm-mlmr6
\font\fiverm=rm-mlmr5
\font\teni=mlmmi10 % math italic
\font\preloaded=mlmmi9
\font\preloaded=mlmmi8
\font\seveni=mlmmi7
\font\preloaded=mlmmi6
\font\fivei=mlmmi5
\font\tensy=mlmsy10 % math symbols
\font\preloaded=mlmsy9
\font\preloaded=mlmsy8
\font\sevensy=mlmsy7
\font\preloaded=mlmsy6
\font\fivesy=mlmsy5
\font\tenex=mlmex10 % math extension
\font\preloaded=rm-mlmss10 % sans serif
%\font\preloaded=rm-mlmssq8
\font\preloaded=rm-mlmsso10 % sans serif italic
%\font\preloaded=rm-mlmssqi8
\font\tenbf=rm-mlmbx10 % boldface extended
\font\preloaded=rm-mlmbx9
\font\preloaded=rm-mlmbx8
\font\sevenbf=rm-mlmbx7
\font\preloaded=rm-mlmbx6
\font\fivebf=rm-mlmbx5
\font\tentt=rm-mlmtt10 % typewriter
\font\preloaded=rm-mlmtt9
\font\preloaded=rm-mlmtt8
\font\preloaded=rm-mlmtto10 % slanted typewriter
\font\tensl=rm-mlmro10 % slanted roman
\font\preloaded=rm-mlmro9
\font\preloaded=rm-mlmro8
\font\tenit=rm-mlmri10 % text italic
\font\preloaded=rm-mlmri9
\font\preloaded=rm-mlmri8
\font\preloaded=rm-mlmri7
\font\preloaded=rm-mlmu10 % unslanted text italic
\font\preloaded=mlmmib10 % bold math italic
\font\preloaded=mlmbsy10 % bold math symbols
\font\preloaded=rm-mlmcsc10 % caps and small caps
%\font\preloaded=rm-mlmssbx10 % sans serif bold extended
%\font\preloaded=rm-mlmdunh10 % Dunhill style
\font\preloaded=rm-mlmr7 scaled \magstep4 % for titles
\font\preloaded=rm-mlmtt10 scaled \magstep2
\font\preloaded=rm-mlmssbx10 scaled \magstep2

\let\preloaded=\undefined % preloaded fonts must be declared anew later.

\skewchar\teni='177 \skewchar\seveni='177 \skewchar\fivei='177
\skewchar\tensy='60 \skewchar\sevensy='60 \skewchar\fivesy='60

\textfont0=\tenrm \scriptfont0=\sevenrm \scriptscriptfont0=\fiverm
\def\rm{\fam\z@\tenrm}
\textfont1=\teni \scriptfont1=\seveni \scriptscriptfont1=\fivei
\def\mit{\fam\@ne} \def\oldstyle{\fam\@ne\teni}
\textfont2=\tensy \scriptfont2=\sevensy \scriptscriptfont2=\fivesy
\def\cal{\fam\tw@}
\textfont3=\tenex \scriptfont3=\tenex \scriptscriptfont3=\tenex
\newfam\itfam \def\it{\fam\itfam\tenit} % \it is family 4
\textfont\itfam=\tenit
\newfam\slfam \def\sl{\fam\slfam\tensl} % \sl is family 5
\textfont\slfam=\tensl
\newfam\bffam \def\bf{\fam\bffam\tenbf} % \bf is family 6
\textfont\bffam=\tenbf \scriptfont\bffam=\sevenbf
\scriptscriptfont\bffam=\fivebf
\newfam\ttfam \def\tt{\fam\ttfam\tentt} % \tt is family 7
\textfont\ttfam=\tentt

\tenrm

Abc {\it def\/} {\sl ghi\/} {\bf jkl}

$a+b+\alpha$

$$
\sum+\int_\Gamma
$$

\bye
```

I found the names by looking in the `.fd` files.

[image]

Running `pdffonts` on the PDF file shows

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
VAJVJL+MLMRoman10-Regular            Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       4  0
XAMRRZ+MLMRoman10-Italic             Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       5  0
QLCGIE+MLMRomanSlant10-Regular       Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       6  0
BUCLYS+MLMRoman10-Bold               Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       7  0
HJQQGN+MLMMathItalic10-Regular       Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       8  0
LGTMNF+MLMMathExtension10-Regular    Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       9  0
CMLUYB+MLMRoman7-Regular             Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      10  0
```

Comment: The lines with `\font\preloaded` isn't needed in a macro file unused for generating format. And this trick is irrelevant at all today even if a format is generated. Time is hardly saved but the .fmt file is larger.

Answer (score 2):

**For plain TeX.** Copy commands `\font` (lines 400--467) from `plain.tex`, remove all commands `\font\preloaded...` and replace names `cm*` to corresponding existing names of files from the directory `fonts/tfm/public/mlmodern/`. You have to choose one of encoding for text fonts `cs-` or `ec-` or `qx-` etc. and use only these file names for text fonts. Math fonts `mlm*` correspond to original `cm*`. Save this to your macro file. Add lines 477--492 with `\textfont...` from `plain.tex` too.

**For OpTeX.** Key information is written in the `mlmodern` doc: "*OpenType support is planned for future version*". I recommend you to ask the authors if this plan in realized. If not then non ASCII languages cannot be simply used with this old `mlmodern` font implementation. Note that we have Unicode machine LuaTeX and we need Unicode fonts. Doing some very specific re-encodnig macro tricks are not good idea when we have hundreds OpenType fonts with high quality today.

If you have a "future version" from authors with OpenType fonts mentioned in the documentation then you can copy the file `f-lmfonts.opm` to `f-mlmodern.opm` and rename the names of the `.otf` files here to real `.otf` files in your computer. Then use `\fontfam[mlmodern]`.

If you are using only ASCII language then you can copy files `fonts-preload.opm` and `math-preload.opm` and modify `tfm` names here to the existing names (similary like with `plain.tex` file). But this approach has no future: we need modern fonts when we are using modern TeX engine. No old fonts where `modern` is only in their names.

Comment: I am totally satisfied with US-ASCII, and I actually want to read old-fashioned fonts.